# Fatal error: Call to undefined function context_get()

Tags: 7

I got an error after trying to update two modules:

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined function context_get() in
>   sites/all/modules/context/context_ui/context_ui.module on line 422`

Also:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. HTTP Result Code: 200 Debugging information follows. Path: http://redneckrampage.ee/authorize.php?batch=1&render=overlay&id=78&op=do StatusText: OK ResponseText: Fatal error: Call to undefined function context_get() in sites/all/modules/context/context_ui/context_ui.module on line 422
```

Any ideas on how to fix this without deleting/renaming the module folder on the server?

Drupal version 7.22

Comment: Did you check this [link](https://drupal.org/node/1099106) before,might be helpful

Comment: TY arpitr. But I managed to solve the problem already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing Context module and if this does not solve, also also try installing the spaces module.

Comment: Yeah, deleting the module folder and manually reinstalling it got me out of the error page. What caused the errors in the first place was the fact that when updating the modules I couldn't overwrite the files in the modules folder. Updating the Drupal core solved the overwriting issue.TY Neo!